# Match exact word in a line - Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I'm trying to identify exact match of a string in line. But couldn't able to get the actual required output.

Line

```
# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: accnt group::--x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::r-x default:other::r-x  user:an:rw-
```

Pattern

```
user::rwx
```

Command

```
echo "# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: accnt group::--x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::r-x default:other::r-x  user:an:rw-" | grep -w "user::rwx" | wc -l
```

Expected Output

```
0
```

Actual Output

```
1
```

Other options tried

```
echo "# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: accnt group::--x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::r-x default:other::r-x  user:an:rw-" | fgrep -x "user::rwx" | wc -l

echo "# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: accnt group::--x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::r-x default:other::r-x  user:an:rw-" | grep -Eo "user::rwx" | wc -l

echo "# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: accnt group::--x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::r-x default:other::r-x  user:an:rw-" | grep -wo "user::rwx" | wc -l
```

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: If I got to correctly, you want to print `0` when a complete match is found? If this is not correct then could you please be more clear in your question.

Comment: No I want to return the string if match is found else it has to be blank.Im not getting the correct value when I use the command with changing the pattern awk -v var="group::--x" 'match($0,var OFS){print 0}'

Comment: Can you edit your answer for the requirements? Perhaps use `line="# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: accnt group::--x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::r-x default:other::r-x  user:an:rw-"` and `echo "${line}"| grep 'user::rwx'`. Or do you want the substring with the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below command and see if this works for all the scenarios which you are looking for.
`echo .. | grep -oP '\suser::rwx\s' | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to print lines which having exact words then try following.

```
var="user::rwx"
awk -v var="$var" 'match($0,var){count++} END{print count}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. This will print 0 in case of any exact match found in any of the line of your file.

```
var="user::rwx"
awk -v var="$var" 'match($0,var){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

IMHO, why OP's code is not working since OP is using wc command which will give count of lines in output but looks looks like OP wants to print `0` when a match found (if I am not wrong here)

Comment: Where is the part of the answer that explains why OP's attempt didn't work

Comment: @Inian, Added it now, one more request which I always do to you, please be little polite while asking questions, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: ```awk``` command which you specified doesn't work for all scenarios. Im not getting the correct value when I use the command with changing the pattern ```awk -v var="group::--x" 'match($0,var OFS){print 0}' ```

Comment: @contactaps, ok sure, I edited my code it will print the matched content. So you want to print non-matched or blank for each line of your Input_file? Can you please confirm the same?

Comment: @contactaps, Could you please check my EDIT solution and lemme know if that helps you? This will give number of lines matched count, lemme know if I could help further here.

Answer (score 0):

Your line seems to contain the mentioned word, in this part:

```
default:user::rwx
```

You mention you don't want this (only the part where `user::rwx` as a whole should be taken into account), so why not simply add the beginning space into your `grep`, like this:

```
echo ... | grep -w " user::rwx" | wc -l    # mind the space in front of "user"
```

(I tried it on my Ubuntu subsystem and it seems to do the trick)